# How do you increase the pickradius of a matplotlib Line2D artist?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contains, picker

I would like to create plot where each point is an individual artist that can be picked. This is my current solution:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import \
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        a = [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(100)]
        b = [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(100)]
        self.artists = []
        self.last_artist = None
        for x, y in zip(a, b):
            artist = self.ax.plot(
                x, y, 'o', picker=True, pickradius=6, color='#ff4500'
            )
            self.artists += artist

        self.canvas.draw()

        self.cid_motion = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.hover
        )

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def hover(self, event):
        if event.inaxes == self.ax:
            ind = 0
            cont = None
            while (
                ind in range(len(self.artists))
                and not cont
            ):
                artist = self.artists[ind]
                cont, _ = artist.contains(event)
                if cont:
                    if artist is not self.last_artist:
                        if self.last_artist is not None:
                            self.last_artist.set_path_effects(
                                [PathEffects.Normal()]
                            )
                            self.last_artist.set_zorder(2)
                        artist.set_path_effects(
                            [PathEffects.withStroke(
                                linewidth=7, foreground="c", alpha=0.4
                            )]
                        )
                        artist.set_zorder(3)
                        self.last_artist = artist
                ind += 1

            if not cont and self.last_artist is not None:
                self.last_artist.set_path_effects([PathEffects.Normal()])
                self.last_artist.set_zorder(2)
                self.last_artist = None
            self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, the highlighting *only* works if you hover *exactly* over the center of a data point, it doesn't matter if you increase the `pickradius`. So I thought maybe I could change the `contains` method, but I don't know how. I found that matplotlib `Artists` come with a [`set_contains` method](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_contains.html) which you can use to come up with your own `contains` method. But I don't know how to do that. I was hoping I could learn from how the default `contains` method is implemented and looked at the [source code](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/artist.html#Artist), but unfortunately this doesn't expain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pickradius` combined with `picker` as bool should achieve what you intend to. However, it is not doing so. On the other hand, `picker` if defined a float, is used as the pick radius in points. Therefore, specifying the tolerance directly to `picker` makes thing work. Change the following line:

```
        artist = self.ax.plot(
            x, y, 'o', picker=True, pickradius=6, color='#ff4500'
        )
```

to

```
        artist = self.ax.plot(
            x, y, 'o', picker=6, color='#ff4500'
        )
```

Comment: That's crazy, thank you! So I guess this is a bug in matplotlib?

Comment: Possibly. I am a newbie to `matplotlib`. Just helping people to get a hook. This is like the second instant a workaround solution that worked. I will take note of these and report to the community and see if they really are a bug.

Comment: Note that `True` is the same as `1`. And if `picker` is a number, the pickradius is set to that number. Since keywordarguments are read in reverse order, `picker=True, pickradius=6` simply means: "Set the radius to 6; then set the radius to 1."

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for clarifying. OPs issue seems to be a common one. Isn't it counter-intuitive that the keyword arguments reading order creates such an issue?

Comment: Oh, might be. But also note that `picker=True` isn't really supported. It just works coincidently.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest `picker` by itself can be bool or float as seen from [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html). So I assume it being bool is valid. Isn't it?

Comment: I see. So this is either a bug in the documentation or a bug in the code. Because there is no explicit check for a bool present. (You could in fact put `picker="yes", pickradius=10` in there, and it would work.) Feel free to create an issue about this, because *something* needs to change.

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys! That's very interesting. I learned more than I hoped for.